# What is the etymology of the kanji 金?

Tags: kanji, etymology

Trying to look up the etymology of the kanji 金, every reference seems to give a different explanation. Let me ask about two references (Wiktionary and Hanziyuan)

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%87%91) gives the following etymology

> semantic 王 (“upside-down axe”) + semantic 呂 (“two blocks of metal”) + phonetic 亼. 亼 is the ancient form for 今.

Hanziyuan said that in decomposition notes

> (- musical bell indicating metal)

I want to know the real etymology for this kanji and if it is one of these two, I want to understand why.

I mean, if the Wiktionary explanation is correct then why is the upside-down axe part of the character; if the Hanziyuan explanation is correct, then how does the musical bell indicate the metal and where is this musical bell in kanji?

Comment: You can take Wiktionary's explanation as correct, and *Hanziyuan*'s explanation as wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

「[金]{きん}」can indeed be viewed as containing semantic「呂」, semantic「王」, and phonetic「[今]{きん}」.

> 「王」is a depiction of the blade of a *battle axe*, used as a *symbol of power/authority* > *king* > *prince*.
>
> <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
> [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
> [image]
> 小臣卣
> [集成5378](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=5378&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
> 金
> [image]
> 大盂鼎
> [集成2837](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2837&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>今
> [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
> [image]</kbd>
>
> In「金」,「王」is being used for the meaning *metal* *(battle-axe)*, emphasised here as an item of metallic manufacture.
>
> ---
>
> As discussed [before](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65804/what-is-the-etymology-of-the-kanji-%E9%A3%9F/65809#65809),「亼」is a *component* in「今」. The more complex story is that, early on during the Shang Dynasty, both「亼」and「今」were used to represent the same word.「亼」is「口」written upside-down, while「今」is「曰」(*to speak*) written upside-down. The shape of「曰」is derived from「口」; see [What's the deal with/origin of the character 曰?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3635/whats-the-deal-with-origin-of-the-character-%E6%9B%B0).
>
> <kbd>商
> [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
> [image]
> [後](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)1.11.9
> [合集36955](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=36955&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>商
> 甲
> [image]
> [鐵](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)110.4
> [合集6038](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=6038&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
> 金
> [image]
> 夨令方彝
> [集成9901](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9901&jgwfl=)</kbd>
> <kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
> [image]
> [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
> 　<kbd>[東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han)
> [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
> [image]
> 老子銘碑</kbd>
> 　<kbd>今
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>
>
> 「今」is no longer used nowadays for its original meaning, which is now written as「吟・噤」.「今」(Zhengzhang OC: **/*krɯm/**) was originally a depiction of a *blocked mouth*, indicating the meaning *unable to speak*, and it may share etymology with「禁」(also **/*krɯm/**; *taboo, warning, prohibition*).
>
> ---
>
> 「呂」depicts *metal disks/plates*, representing a word now written as「鋁」(*copper plates*, now re-interpreted as *aluminium*).
>
> <kbd>商
> 甲
> [image]
> [乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)8854
> [合集22265](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=22265&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
> 金
> [image]
> 貉子卣
> [集成5409](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=5409&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
> 金
> [image]
> 效父簋
> [集成3822](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=3822&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
> [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
> [image]
> [上・䊷](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)・15</kbd>
> 　
> <kbd>篆
> [image]
> 說文解字</kbd>
> 　<kbd>今
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>
>
> > Note:「呂」had the same graphical origins as「⼎」, both representing *metal disks/plates* made from a forging process. While「呂」represented a word now written as「鋁」,「⼎」represented a word now written as「鉼」(*metal plates*).
> >
> > You may later come across resources telling you that「⼎」means *ice*, commonly used as a semantic component to do with *ice/cold*. In truth, this is a phonetic loan;「⼎」>「鉼」sounded similar to the word now written as「冰」(*Shinjitai:*「氷」; *ice*), and was used early on to represent this word.

Bringing these components together:

<kbd>西周
金
[image]
過伯簋
[集成3907](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=3907&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
金
[image]
師㝨簋
[集成4313](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4313&jgwfl=)</kbd>
<kbd>篆
[image]
說文解字</kbd>
　<kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
簡
[image]
[日甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)90背</kbd>
　<kbd>今
楷
[image]</kbd>

---

**References**:

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究{{kr:所}}《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)

Comment: So this page here is wrong http://www.guoxuedashi.com/zidian/ziyuan_1352.html

Comment: @user32763 it's not quite wrong. The crucible explanation is also reported in some reliable references. The only thing is that we should expect an individual crucible shape, (that is, without「呂・⼎」) representing a word that meant *crucible* in the earliest inscriptions, but such a character has not been found. The part of that explanation which says「呂・⼎」is the earliest form of「金」is probably not reliable. (Wait a moment, do you read Chinese? Or are you guessing what the explanations are from the pictures given?)

Comment: no i can't read chinese ..but first i translated the site  in the search page and i found link "character source analyze 1" so i opened it..second when i saw the picture haven't the battle axe i downloaded it then after about hour trying to exctract the text then translated it. .. but you know ..the kanji and the chinese culture and the japanese culture deserve all the efforts