# Is the water radical sometimes three strokes and sometimes two strokes?

Tags: radicals

凍, does it have the water radical on the left? Why is this three strokes in some words and two strokes in others?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_85 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_15

Answer (score 7):

While 「氵」 is indeed an abbreviation of 「水」 (*water*), it is rather unfortunate that the colloquial name of 「冫」 in both Chinese and Japanese implies that 「冫」 has something to do with *water*. To emphasise, **「冫」 does not have anything to do with *water***, unless the appearance of 「冫」 is due to graphical corruption from 「氵」.

---

<kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
⿱一丞卣
[集成5318](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=5318&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
日乙227 冬
[睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd><kbd>今
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

「冫」 was originally a picture of *forged metal plates*, now written as 「鉼」 ([Zhengzhang OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Zhengzhang_(1981%E2%80%931995)): **/*peŋʔ/**). It was later borrowed to represent the [morpheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morpheme) now written as 「冰」 (**/*pŋrɯŋ/**, *ice*) via the [rebus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus#Rebus_principle).

As a stand-alone character, 「冫」 thus represents the two morphemes

- [鉼]{へい}, *metal (plates)*
- [冰]{ひょう} (*Shinjitai*: 氷), *ice*

---

In accordance with how Chinese characters work, as a character component, 「冫」 may impart either a meaning hint, a sound hint, or both a meaning and sound hint to the character it is part of. These meaning and sound hints are taken from the morphemes that it represents; that is, if you see 「冫」 as part of a character 「Ｘ」, you should be thinking to yourself about one of the following:

- Ｘ sounds like **へい**
- Ｘ sounds like **ひょう**
- Ｘ has something to do with *metal (plates)*
- Ｘ has something to do with *ice*
- Ｘ both sounds like **へい** and has something to do with *metal (plates)*
- Ｘ both sounds like **ひょう** and has something to do with *ice*

**Examples:**

- 冶 - *to smelt metal*
- 匀 - *ancient weight measurement*, now written as 「鈞」
- 金 - **きん**, *metal*, compound of 「冫」 (*metal plates*), semantic 「王」 (*metal battle weapon* > *power/authority* > *king*) and phonetic [「今」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=84) (also **きん**). See [What is the etymology of the kanji 金?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65883/what-is-the-etymology-of-the-kanji-%e9%87%91/65886#65886)
- 冷 - *cold*
- 冬 - *winter*
- 凍 - *freeze*
- 馮 - **びょう**, **ひょう**

---

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a hint:

In 冷たい、the key on the left side in the kanji 冷 depicts : "ice with a few cracks on it".
Source: [https://www.amazon.com/Key-Kanji-History-Characters-Japanese/dp/0887277365](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0887277365)

I cannot affirm with certitude that is the same radical as in 凍 though.

Comment: FYI: that description of 冫 is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The [radical on the left of 冷 and 凍](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_15) is called にすい (二水) but it's not [the usual "water radical"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_85) which is さんずい (三水). You'll just have to count the strokes.